# Module returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, lodash

I have a simple module return which makes a bunch of API calls to retrieve data and then return it

```
export default async function getCandles(coins) {
  let data = [];
  _.forEach(coins, async coin => {
    let candles1h = await client.candles({
      symbol: coin,
      interval: "1h",
      limit: 500
    });
    let candles2h = await client.candles({
      symbol: coin,
      interval: "2h",
      limit: 500
    });
    let candles4h = await client.candles({
      symbol: coin,
      interval: "4h",
      limit: 500
    });
    let candles1d = await client.candles({
      symbol: coin,
      interval: "1d",
      limit: 500
    });

    let candles = {
      "1h": candles1h,
      "2h": candles2h,
      "4h": candles4h,
      "1d": candles1d
    };

    data.push({ coin: candles });
  });

  return data;
}
```

And I've got a test file which inputs the array parameter and sends it

```
async function test() {
  let candles = await getCandles(coins);

  console.log(candles);
}
```

When I call the test function, the output is just an empty array. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getCandles()` has no way of knowing when each of the batches of async functions `lodash.forEach()` creates resolves.

One solution might be to call your batches of async functions using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). `Promise.all()` is `await`able and enables multiple calls to be sent simultaneously, rather than sequentially.

See below for a rough example.

```
// Get Candles.
const getCandles = async symbol => {
  const intervals = ['1h', '2h', '4h', '1d']
  const limit = 500
  const candles = await Promise.all(intervals.map(async interval => await client.candles({symbol, interval, limit})))
  return candles.reduce(async (c, x, i) => {
    c[intervals[i]] = x
    return c
  }, {})
}

// Get Coins.
const getCoins = async symbols => {
  const coins = symbols.map(async symbol => ({coin: await getCandles(symbol)}))
  return await Promise.all(coins)
}

// Test.
const test = async () => await getCoins(symbols)
```

Comment: `coins` is an array of symbols which are parameters(symbols) and I intend to await for candlestick data, bundle it into an object(1h, 2h, 4h and 1d) and then return. I partially do not understand your code and was looking at `Promise.all()` for a while

Comment: Yeah, I changed the language a little (from coins to symbols) and split the functions for legibility. The overall objective is still the same. Essentially, the problem is that `getCandles()` isn't waiting for `lodash.forEach()` to resolve. `Promise.all()` provides a way to signal when to resolve and run multiple calls simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry if my answer was cryptic. I've tried to boil down the crux of it. Let me know if that works  @Satonamo

Answer (score 0):

I think I will do this. But I'm not sure I have not tried it.

```
export default async function getCandles(coins) {
  return await _.map(coins, async coin => {
    let candles1h = await client.candles({
      symbol: coin,
      interval: "1h",
      limit: 500
    });
    let candles2h = await client.candles({
      symbol: coin,
      interval: "2h",
      limit: 500
    });
    let candles4h = await client.candles({
      symbol: coin,
      interval: "4h",
      limit: 500
    });
    let candles1d = await client.candles({
      symbol: coin,
      interval: "1d",
      limit: 500
    });

    return {
      coin: {
        "1h": candles1h,
        "2h": candles2h,
        "4h": candles4h,
        "1d": candles1d
      }
    };
  });
}
```